# Getting Null in g-recaptcha-response Google's reCaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google's reCaptcha v.2.0 but i am getting null in **g-recaptcha-response** due to this reCaptcha is not working properly and I am always getting the error that **Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.** even if I successfully submitted the Captcha. I `var_dump` the `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` and I am getting `null`. Please help me. Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin-left: 230px; margin-top: 40px;" data-sitekey="MySiteKey"></div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'My Site Secret Key';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if ($responseData->success) {
            // My All Logic Here
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    }
}
```

I am always getting the error **Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.** on successful submission too. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Note:-** There is no **table** tag used in between the Form.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue. The strangest part is a client-side call to `grecaptcha.getResponse()` returns to correct response. For some reason it's just not setting **g-recaptcha-response**.
So my workaround was to set a data-callback function to populate a hidden field with the response and use that server-side instead. The hidden input also helps with ease of client-side validation.
**eg:**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="captcha_onclick" data-sitekey="######"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha" id="recaptchaValidator" />
```

**javascript:**

```
function captcha_onclick() {
    document.getElementById('recaptchaValidator').value = grecaptcha.getResponse();
}
```

**server-side:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['recaptcha'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['recaptcha'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bug in their code, this should not be necessary, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're submitting the form without an actual **submit button**, but I've copy/pasted your code and it works for me. I did change the error arrays into echo to display the `else` messages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin-left: 230px; margin-top: 40px;" data-sitekey="Your-Public-Site-Key"></div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        if( isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {

            //your site secret key
            $secret = 'Your-Private-Site-Key';

            //get verify response data
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

            if($responseData->success) {

                // My All Logic Here
                echo 'Success Message';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
            } 
        }
        else {
            echo 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
        }
    }
?>
```